# unable to extract date in Mysql when using in where clause in the imdb dataset

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

This code is ending up with 0 values:

```sql
SELECT count(m.id), median_rating
FROM movie as m 
INNER JOIN ratings as r ON m.id=r.movie_id
where  median_rating=8 
AND date_published between str_to_date('01-04-2018','%d-%m-%y') 
                       AND str_to_date('2019-04-01','%y-%m-%d');
```

Also for Column: date_published Definition is: date_published date

So I want to extract the date in date format from the texts so that I can use it while filtering but its not working,
I tried with string format of dates and the code is working (  WHERE median_rating = 8 AND date_published BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2019-04-01' )
but its not working when I try to extract the dates and compare :/

Comment: Use standard mySQL date format yyyy-mm-dd: it saves typing and will run faster because no additional function/formatting calls. Also can use indexes

Comment: *not working* ? What actually happens? Please [edit] your question to let us know. Your query looks OK, even if the two different date formats you use are a little peculiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
%Y  Year, numeric, four digits
%y  Year, numeric (two digits)
```

Using the code for two-digit years does not match your input values.

Demo:

```
select str_to_date('01-04-2018','%d-%m-%y') as date;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2020-04-01 |
+------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '01-04-2018'

select str_to_date('2019-04-01','%y-%m-%d');
+--------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('2019-04-01','%y-%m-%d') |
+--------------------------------------+
| NULL                                 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Warning (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: '2019-04-01' for function str_to_date
```

Both dates can be parsed if you use the format code for four-digit year, `%Y`.

Comment: Thank you ! 
got this with your help :)